# Unable to Reload friend list table from google plus call back function from another view controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, google-plus, nsnotificationcenter

*I'm trying to fetch all the people list in google plus and it works but the problem is that it works fine only for a already logged in user, if a user attempts a fresh login the table doesnt get reloaded I need to go back and click on the G+ friends button again to load the data. I've noticed that if the user session status is not authenticated and when he clicks on the G+ friends button he is prompted with login and the call back function (finishedWithAuth) which is in my SignupViewController gets called. So what I did was created an object for my FrienListViewController which displays the friend list and call its viewdidLoad method in the G+ call back function, every function seems to get called and on NSLog I'm also getting the people list and images but **the table doesnt get reloaded at all, it doesnt call any tableview methods when the call is made from viewDidLoad**, I did some search and **tried to implement the NSNotification Center, but the selector method never gets called.** May be I'm implementing it in wrong way. Can you check my code and help me with any suitable workaround?*

**SignupViewController.m**

```
//Google Plus callback method

-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{

    AppDelegate * appdelegate =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:[GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"] completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
     {
         [appdelegate hideLoading];
         if(error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Authentication Error: %@", error);
         }
         else
         {

           if([Reusables getDefaultValue:@"fetchGoogleFriends"])
             {
                 FriendListViewController *ob= [[FriendListViewController alloc]init];
                 [ob viewDidLoad];
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
             }

         }

     }];


}
```

**FriendListViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.friendListSection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",@"#",nil];

    listType=[Reusables getDefaultValue:@"friendListType"];

    AppDelegate * appdelegate =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appdelegate showLoading];

    [self fetchFriendList];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchPeopleImagesInBackground) withObject:nil];
    //[friendsTable reloadData];
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (objFirstViewController) name:@"MyNotification" object:self];


//This logs returns <Friendviewcontroller> in beginning but returns null when the view didload is called from the G+ callback function, Any suggestions ?
        NSLog(@"Table Delegate: %@",friendsTable.delegate);

}

//This method doesnt get called
-(void)objFirstViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [friendsTable reloadData];
}
```

**These are some other important function for fetching friends, look this if u cant able to figure out error in previous methods**

```
-(void)fetchFriendList
{
     if ([listType isEqualToString:@"GooglePlus"])
    {
        if ([GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication)
        {
            NSLog(@"Status is authenticated, fetching friends!!");
        [self fetchGooglePlusFriends:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
        }
        else
        {
       [Reusables storeDataToDefaults:@"fetchGoogleFriends" objectToAdd:@"Enabled"];
        [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]authenticate];

        }

    }

//Google Plus Fetching friends function
- (void)fetchGooglePlusFriends:(NSString *)collection {

    AppDelegate * appdelegate =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // 1. Create a |GTLQuery| object to list people that are visible to this
    // sample app.
    GTLQueryPlus *query =
    [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                    collection:collection];

    // 2. Execute the query.
    [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:query
                                         completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                             GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 if ([listType isEqualToString:@"GooglePlus"])
                                                 {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);


                                                     [appdelegate hideLoading];
                                                 }

                                             } else {
                                                 // Get an array of people from |GTLPlusPeopleFeed| and reload
                                                 // the table view.
                                                 _peopleList = peopleFeed.items;


                                                 // Render the status of the Google+ request.
                                                 NSNumber *count = peopleFeed.totalItems;
                                                 if (count.intValue == 1) {

                                                 } else {
                                                                                                            NSLog(@"Status: Listed %@ people, listtype:%@, gplusshow:%@", count,listType,[Reusables getDefaultValue:@"fetchGoogleFriends"]);
                                                 }
                                                 if ([listType isEqualToString:@"GooglePlus"]||[Reusables getDefaultValue:@"fetchGoogleFriends"])
                                                 {

                                                     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchPeopleImagesInBackground) withObject:nil];
                                                     [friendsTable reloadData];
                                                     [appdelegate hideLoading];
                                                 }

                                             }
                                         }];
}
```

***NSLog(@"Table Delegate: %@",friendsTable.delegate); returns Friendviewcontroller in beginning but returns null when the view didload is called from the G+ callback function, this is the main problem. Any suggestions ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this........

```
 if([Reusables getDefaultValue:@"fetchGoogleFriends"])
    {

    FriendListViewController *ob= (FriendListViewController*)[self.navigationController topViewController];
    [ob viewDidLoad];
    [ob.friendsTable reloadData];


    }
```